# Android 11 - list files in Documents folder

Tags: android, app-inventor

[image: my blocks]I wrote an app to list documents folder, it runs well also with android 11, but I can no longer modify or recompile it My Blocks

Comment: Please [take the tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). 
You might want to edit your question and add a screenshot of your **relevant** blocks.

Comment: your question already has been answered in the App Inventor community here https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/android-11-and-storage-file/34154/41?u=taifun

Comment: I would read/write textfiles in Documents folder, not in asd.

Comment: your questions was **how to list files in the Documents folder**... and [this was the answer given by @Anke there](https://community.appinventor.mit.edu/t/android-11-and-storage-file/34154/41?u=taifun)... also if you have follow up questions what prevents you from continuing the discussion there?